# Наследование в JAVA. Расширение возможностей базового класса

Tags: java, ооп

В одном из курсов по изучению JAVA услышал фразу :

> *"В классе наследнике можно добавлять поля и методы, тем самым расширяя возможности базового класса".*

Я понял эту фразу так, что если в классе наследнике объявить метод, то метод наследника автоматом будет числиться как метод родительского класса.  Такая типа копилочка получается. Но на деле это не работает, значит неправильно понял. Объясните пож-а, где я ошибаюсь.

```
public class Mother {
    void callSun(){
    System.out.println("Игорь! Иди ко мне!");
}
public class Sun extends Mother {
     void searchMother (){
        System.out.println("Мама!!!");
    }
```

Имея на руках экземпляры классов, в вышеприведенном коде `class Sun`(наследник) может пользоваться как своим методом, так и методом `class Mother` (родителя), а родитель уже не может пользоваться методом наследника. Что полностью противоречит тому, как я понял цитату.

Comment: _sun_ - это _солнце_. _son_ - это _сын_.

Comment: @Regent а палллин точно, спасибо, а я еще думаю что это Sun Microsystems такое название чудное себе выбрало )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я понял эту фразу так, что если в классе наследнике объявить метод, то метод наследника автоматом будет числиться как метод родительского класса. Такая типа копилочка получается.

Вы неправильно поняли эту фразу.

Допустим, Вы определили некоторый базовый класс (*суперкласс*) со своими полями и методами. Далее Вы определили дочерний класс (*подкласс*). При этом, подкласс имеет доступ к полям и методам (**с поправкой на модификаторы доступа**) суперкласса.

Суперкласс – это некоторый фундамент, на основе которого строятся подклассы.

В подклассах определяются свои поля и методы – подкласс *расширяет* возможности суперкласса.

Comment: это я теперь понял, может какая то другая возможность расширяется у базового класса? Что мог иметь ввиду этот автор заявляя это?

Comment: @SergioBerluskony, У базового класса ничего не расширяется. **Расширение** заключается в том, что подкласс имеет доступ к полям и методам суперкласса и, при этом, **в подклассе определяются свои поля и методы**.

Comment: да, дошло наконец! Это как бы...мои дети продолжают мое дело и развиваются, я дал им все что мог для этого )